# Difference between sed -e and sed -f

Tags: unix, sed

What is the difference between `sed -e` and `sed -f` options. Which of these should be used for in place editing. 
I was not able to understand their meaning clearly from the man pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the manual page of [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html)

-e script
--expression=script
Add the commands in script to the set of commands to be run while processing the input

This means that sed would be executing the commands passed directly to it on the command-line itself such as `sed -e 's/foo/bar/g'`

Where as,
-f script-file
--file=script-file
Add the commands contained in the file script-file to the set of commands to be run while processing the input.

while using -f sed would be expecting the commands in the file specified after `-f` option. This is generally useful for complex operations.

As long as in place editing is concerned, any of the options can be used. For example:

`sed -i -e 's/foo/bar/g'`

Answer (score 1):

`sed -e <commands>` executes the commands passed on the command line, like `sed -e s/foo/bar/`, while `sed -f <file>` executes the commands found in the passed file.

None of them relate to inplace editing. That's `-i <backup_extension>`. If no extension is passed (like `sed -i '' -e s/foo/bar/ file_to_edit`), no backup is made.